# Ошибка при использовании do while для вывода случайных записей из БД?

Tags: java, sql

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

        //Объявим переменные компонентов
        EditText editText;
        TextView text1;

        private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);



        try {
            mDBHelper.updateDataBase();
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            throw new Error("UnableToUpdateDatabase");
        }

        try {
            mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            throw mSQLException;
        }

        //Найдем компоненты в XML разметке

        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        editText =  findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final int[] a = {0};
        final int[] x = {0};
        do {


            String product = "";
            String gono = "";


            final Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + "book1" +    " ORDER BY RANDOM() ", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if ((cursor!=null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)){
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                product += cursor.getString(1);
                gono += cursor.getString(2);
            }
            cursor.close();

            text1.setText(product);


            final String finalGono = gono;

            editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                        if (editText.getText().toString().equals(finalGono))
                            a[0]++;
                        else
                            x[0]++; 
                    }
                    return false;
               }
            });
        }  while (a[0] > 2*x[0]);
    }
}
```

При запросе из БД в `TextViev (text1)` текста вопроса нужно после ответа в EditText вывести следующую рандомную строку вопроса, при этом учитывая количество правильных и неправильных ответов через числовые переменные ( "а" и "х"). Написал следующий код. Почему то после ответа не загружает текст следующего вопроса(в `rawQuery` `product` - это текст вопроса, а `gono` - правильный ответ,хранящийся в БД, который сравниваем с введенным значением через `OnKeyListener`). Подскажите,пожалуйста,где оступился.

Comment: Исправьте  `if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))` на  if ((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))` . Также, проблема может быть в том, что вы `a` и `x` установили как final.

Comment: ничего не поменялось,выводит строчку,но при ответе не выдает следующую